# htmlUnit behaving oddly. I am not able to retrieve correct number of anchor tag or link tags?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-crawler, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit 2.10. I am creating a small link validator for a website. For crawling I am using this. during my research I was trying to crawl : `loans.xxxxxxx.com`. It has 58 anchor tag and 5 link tags.

I am writing a code like this

```
    List<HtmlElement> elementsOfPage = (List<HtmlElement>) htmlPage.getElementsByTagName("link");
    Iterator<HtmlElement> it = elementsOfPage.iterator();
    System.out.println(elementsOfPage.size());
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        HtmlElement htmlElement = it.next();
        System.out.println(htmlElement.toString());
    }
```

I am also doing the same procedure for anchor tag i.e. a. For link it is just showing 3 and for anchor it is just showing 56 even though there are 5 and 58 respectively.

There are some portions in the code which are commented, I thought the web client ignores it, but if you actually print it will show some results actually are from commented code.

// Before running webclient, I have disabled applets,css, javascripts and increased the timeout to be 7seconds.

Why is this behavior odd ?

Answer (score 0):

How do you get such numbers as 58 and 5? I tried to check URL you provided with HtmlUnit 2.10 + JSoup parser. Code is (Groovy, but almost Java):

```
def client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6)
client.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
def page = (HtmlPage)client.getPage("http://loans.bankofamerica.com/en/index.html")
def doc = Jsoup.parse(page.asXml())
println doc.select("a").size()
println doc.select("link").size()
```

Results are 56 and 2. But with default UserAgent

```
def client = new WebClient()
```

Results are 56 and 3! Seems server gives different markup depends on useragent string (and maybe other headers).

Comment: the problem is the html provided does contain all the links, as I am using getContentAsAString and then doing something on it. So when I am printing the string it does contain all the stuff that the view source shows in any browser shows..